# Compatibility JQuery Mobile Beta and PhoneGap 0.9.6

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

After the release of the latest versions of PhoneGap (0.9.6) and JQuery Mobile (1.0b1), I decided to check it out but the default example gives a white screen. Anyone has been trying it ?

My tools : DMS appLaud plugin for Eclipse (very useful to generate the PhoneGap/JQuery workspace configuration btw); 
           Android 2.2 (API 8) ; 
           JQuery 1.5.2.

Regards

Comment: Okay I found out that JQuery must be updated too. So smart. Nevertheless it is not a purely useless question since some hardware functionalities are not anymore accessed through the PhoneGap solution : the device will not vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and am not having any problems, even with `haptic/vibration` control.  I've just confirmed it's working with `0.9.5, 0.9.6, and 1.0.0`.

Did you remember to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?